# php variable is declared, but will not insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, variables, insert, twilio

In one of my scripts, the php $_POST is declaring properly into a variable. When I echo the variable, it displays correctly, however, when I check the database it does not insert correctly. It appears blank. So my guess is that it isn't a problem with the variable, because it is being called back properly. I do not know what the problem is when it inserts.

If needed this is a twilio app, so the application is pulling the recording url from the twilio app, and I am passing a value from the form in which you record. I am just stating this for those who are familiar with twilio Apps.

```
$sayid = $_SESSION['id'];
$hearid = "01";
$sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];



mysql_query("INSERT INTO says (say, hear, sid, time_sent, happy) 
        VALUES('$sayid', '$hearid', '$sayurl.mp3', now(), '$topic' )"); 


echo $topic;
```

I am open to suggestions, I will try them, and tell you if they work or now.

EDIT  if I change the vaiable $topic to = "whatever" it will post "whatever" to the database properly, but once I change it to $_POST['topic'] it begins to post a blank value again. But If I echo $topic anywhere it will post the correct $_POST value

EDIT #2 okay new update, so I changed the variable declaring to $sayid = "20"; $hearid = "01"; $topic = $_POST['topic']; $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; instead of $sayid = "20"; $hearid = "01"; $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; $topic = $_POST['topic']; and I am now getting an output of the php script CREATING 2 NEW RECORDS, one of them has everything on it except for the $topic, and the other has just the $topic, so they are apparently posting all fields, but in two different rows! lol wow what the hell is going on

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: I am simplifying the code for post reasons, I am aware of everything regarding sql injections. Thank you sir

Comment: Which value is not working? What does the final query look like before you enter it into the database?

Comment: what value are you inserting for the `sad` column? What happens to `$topic2` Also, before anyone else comes in and slates you, you should sanitise those variables as you are leaving yourself prone to sql injection.

Comment: Well, i have edited the code, and AGAIN I AM AWARE OF SQL INJECTION, I just simplified the code for this post. With the code, the insert query looks like it supposed to MINUS the $topic variable. It is echoing correctly onto the page to test, SO I know that it is being declared correctly, but for some reason it WILL NOT insert the value into the database for me

Comment: @sinthia v, what do you mean?

Comment: @EVERYONE  if I change the vaiable $topic to = "whatever" it will post "whatever" to the database properly, but once I change it to $_POST['topic'] it begins to post a blank value again. But If I echo $topic anywhere it will post the correct $_POST value

Comment: okay new update, so I changed the variable declaring to $sayid = "20"; $hearid = "01"; $topic = $_POST['topic']; $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; instead of $sayid = "20"; $hearid = "01"; $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; $topic = $_POST['topic']; and I am now getting an output of the php script CREATING 2 NEW RECORDS, one of them has everything on it except for the $topic, and the other has just the $topic, so they are apparently posting all fields, but in two different rows! lol wow what the hell is going on

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$sayid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);
$hearid = "01";
$sayurl = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']);
$topic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic']);
$topic2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic']);

$query = "INSERT INTO says
            (say, hear, sid, time_sent, happy, sad)
          VALUES
            ('$sayid', '$hearid', '$sayurl.mp3', now(), '$topic', '')";

if (!mysql_query($query)) {
  // Handle error here
  // e.g.
  // echo "Oh no! The query failed! Error: ".mysql_error();
}
```

This will probably fix the problem, and will prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: this is what I get You Said Oh no! The query failed! Error: Duplicate entry '.mp3' for key 2

Comment: How does your table structure look?

Comment: id say hear sid time_sent happy sad, but if I change the vaiable $topic to = "whatever" it will post "whatever" to the database properly, but once I change it to $_POST['topic'] it begins to post a blank value again. But If I echo $topic anywhere it will post the correct $_POST value

Comment: What does it typically contain? Please show the real structure of the table, as in describe TABLE_NAME

Comment: honestly it isn't a problem with anything on the table, because like I said, if I change the variable to = "stackoverflow" IT WILL properly insert stackoverflow into the table under the correct field. It just will not if I change ti to the post value, but it will still echo the correct value, it's driving me crazy

Comment: the value will be simple text, it can even be "hello" nothing radical

Comment: okay new update, so I changed the variable declaring to $sayid = "20";
 $hearid = "01";
 $topic = $_POST['topic'];
 $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; instead of $sayid = "20";
 $hearid = "01";
 $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic'];
and I am now getting an output of the php script CREATING 2 NEW RECORDS, one of them has everything on it except for the $topic, and the other has just the $topic, so they are apparently posting all fields, but in two different rows! lol wow what the hell is going on

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the value for "sad".  You can see if there was an error executing the previous SQL statement using [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_error).

Comment: that isn't the problem, the problem is the $topic value will not insert into the database, it just comes up blank

Comment: Then check that you have a field named topic somewhere.

Comment: Hey Anton, I do not think you are reading the code correctly, I am not inserting anything into a field designated topic. I am inserting the $topic variable. That is what is coming up blank. However, I can still echo it onto the webpage and it will echo correctly proving that it isn't blank and it is declaring properly

Comment: Ah, okay, didn't notice the echo at the end. Try something like   ` ' ".$topic." ' ` instead? Why isn't the code tag working? ;/

Comment: So if I get this correctly, it's inserting a row but the "happy" value inserted in the database is empty but when you echo `$topic` below the insert, it's printing the proper value?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the twilio function, but even so, I can't imagine that giving it a problem because it is still following php rules

Comment: okay new update, so I changed the variable declaring to $sayid = "20";
 $hearid = "01";
 $topic = $_POST['topic'];
 $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; instead of $sayid = "20";
 $hearid = "01";
 $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic'];
and I am now getting an output of the php script CREATING 2 NEW RECORDS, one of them has everything on it except for the $topic, and the other has just the $topic, so they are apparently posting all fields, but in two different rows! lol wow what the hell is going on

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
<form action="test.php" type="post">
<input type="text" name="topic" />
</form>
```

and

```
<?php
$input = $_POST['topic'];
echo $input;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO balbal VALUES ('".$input."')") or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

work for you?

Comment: its giving me Duplicate entry '' for key 1

Comment: I opened a new test php and test form php file to do it, and thats what it returned.

Comment: okay new update, so I changed the variable declaring to $sayid = "20";
 $hearid = "01";
 $topic = $_POST['topic'];
 $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; instead of $sayid = "20";
 $hearid = "01";
 $sayurl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic'];
and I am now getting an output of the php script CREATING 2 NEW RECORDS, one of them has everything on it except for the $topic, and the other has just the $topic, so they are apparently posting all fields, but in two different rows! lol wow what the hell is going on

Comment: What if you do `echo $input;` ?

Comment: nothing, I probably did something so small, because I am still trying to focus on this major code, my bad bro. But did you see my new update? I just posted it and it is wierd lol

Comment: Yeah, try isolating the problem by having a page with only that query and a form only. See if that works, if it does then you have something else that's screwing you up.